# My wallet is protected by AES256-CBC, but I forgot part of the password

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery

My AES256 encryption password is 15 characters. The password uses upper and lower case letters, symbols and numbers. I can remember the first 7 characters of the password, but I have forgotten the last 8 characters which are all digits.

To retrieve the password, I'm planning to use brute force using Python to get the last 8 digits, is this possible?

Comment: 8 digits might be a date (YYYYMMDD or MMDDYYYY etc) so I would try some birthdays, anniversaries etc.

Answer (score 1):

8 digits, assuming you mean decimal digits, only have 100000000 possible values.

That's trivial to brute-force.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've done it, I use python to brute force to combine the last 8 decimal digits